# How to compare two files and Display different results for text and for INT

Tags: csv, python-3.6

I am trying to create a program that will compare two csv files and display the results in new csv file.
In csv files cells have text value and integer value as well. I want if the change occurs and the cell value is TEXT it should append True against that value in new csv file and if the change occurs and the cell value is Integer it should append this text "Result is positive: change in value" and "Result is negative: change in value"

Below are the codes:

```
import csv
with open('book1.csv', 'r') as t1:
    old_csv = t1.readlines()
with open('book2.csv', 'r') as t2:
    new_csv = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    line_in_new = 0
    line_in_old = 0
    while line_in_new < len(new_csv) and line_in_old < len(old_csv):
        if old_csv[line_in_old] != new_csv[line_in_new]:
            out_file.write(new_csv[line_in_new])
        else:
            line_in_old += 1
        line_in_new += 1
```

Please guide.

**EDITED**

Hi i have also tried different method but received KeyError: "['XID'] not in index"

Please see my others codes for this same subject also

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = 'Book1.csv'
file2 = 'Book2.csv'
file3 = 'update.csv'

cols_to_show = ['XID', 'TCO', 'Payment Plan','Livable Area','Brochure', 'Banks']

old = pd.read_csv(file1)
new = pd.read_csv(file2)


def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[1] == x[0] else '{0} --> {1}'.format(*x)


old['version'] = 'old'
new['version'] = 'new'

full_set = pd.concat([old, new], ignore_index=True)

changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_show, keep='last')

dupe_names = changes.set_index('XID').index.get_duplicates()

dupes = changes[changes['XID'].isin(dupe_names)]

change_new = dupes[(dupes['version'] == 'new')]
change_old = dupes[(dupes['version'] == 'old')]

change_new = change_new.drop(['version'], axis=1)
change_old = change_old.drop(['version'], axis=1)

change_new.set_index('XID', inplace=True)
change_old.set_index('XID', inplace=True)

diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=change_old, df2=change_new))
diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)

changes['duplicate'] = changes['XID'].isin(dupe_names)
removed_names = changes[(changes['duplicate'] == False) & (changes['version'] == 'old')]
removed_names.set_index('XID', inplace=True)
new_name_set = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_show)

new_name_set['duplicate'] = new_name_set['XID'].isin(dupe_names)

added_names = new_name_set[(new_name_set['duplicate'] == False) & (new_name_set['version'] == 'new')]
added_names.set_index('XID', inplace=True)
print(added_names)
df = pd.concat([diff_output, removed_names, added_names], keys=('changed', 'removed', 'added'))
print(df)
df[cols_to_show].to_csv(file3)
```

Comment: You should use [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) instead of readlines.

Comment: Hi sir,i have also used different codes as i was not getting results from csv reader..please do check and please help me on this..